# Web API null parameter value in POST action

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I'm trying to use angular and asp.net vNext Web API. I have a controller up but when using angular's `$resource` the object values are not resolved (`Post` method parameter is null)

The request itself has nothing out of the ordinary, though it does send json back. I think I've seen somewhere that vNext doesn't support content negotiation yet so maybe that's it. Can anyone confirm or shed some light on the subject?

Also - is there a way to get to the raw post data in Web API? (I'm using the core framework) cause the Request.Form that I know from mvc is not there any more. I tried the `GetFormAsync` but that returns an empty collection.

EDIT:
Confirmed that the reason for not binding the parameter is the fact that data is sent as JSON. When form encoding is used, the parameter values are resolved correctly.

Answer (score 1):

using [FromBody] attribute on the param solved the issue.